# Custom tooltip that can overhang NSWindow?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I need to create a custom tooltip for my app yet I want it to act like a normal tooltip and overhang the top level window if the cursor is near the bottom or right edges. Do I need to make the tooltip control an NSWindow itself or is there a way to get an nsview to pop outside the window bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution for this was to create an NSPanel that is setFloatingPanel:YES. On mouse enter of the view I call orderToFront on the panel, on mouse move I setFrameOrigin and on mouse exit I orderOut.